# For Each loop With nested if not running properly. VB.net

Tags: vb.net, foreach

I have a sub that on a button click is supposed to query my SQL database pull all the results that match ant then weed out the ones that don't fit user defined values.

dt1 and dt2 are datePickers for the start and end date. the date is stored as a string in the database and parsed on retrieval. I know there is something weird with For each loop and DELETE because of index numbers, but all the work around I have tries the IF THEN statement does not run.

```
 Private Sub getdata_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles getdata.Click

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Dispose()
    SQL.AddParam("@name", emplistadm.Text.ToString)

    SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT EmployeeName, PunchIn, PunchOut, HoursWorked FROM PUNCHES WHERE EmployeeName = @name And CurrentStatus = 0 AND Processed = 0")

    Dim dt1 As DateTime = startdate.DisplayDate
    Dim dt2 As DateTime = enddate.DisplayDate

    Dim dt1int As Int16 = DatePart(DateInterval.DayOfYear, dt1)
    Dim dt2int As Int16 = DatePart(DateInterval.DayOfYear, dt2)

    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim dt3 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(dr("PunchIn"))
        Dim dt3int As Int16 = DatePart(DateInterval.DayOfYear, dt3)
        If dt3int > dt2int AndAlso dt3int < dt1int Then
            dr.Delete()
        End If

    Next



    dt = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0)
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView
End Sub
```

I know I need to call the accept changes also but when I replace the dr.delete with msgbox("dakjhfdsalkjf") It still doesn't show the message box.

Comment: Put `Option Strict On` at the top of the source code file.  Now the compiler tells you what you did wrong.

Comment: Are your dates perhaps spanning years? Your integer fields are "the number of days since the start of the year". If the Start was October 1st, 2001, and the end was January 1st 2002, the dt3int variable could never be between the two values.

But, you don't need to do any conversion. You can just compare the date portions using `If dt3.Date > dt2.Date AndAlso dt3.Date < dt1.Date Then`...

Comment: Dates are always with two months so no it is not a year issue

Comment: Also if I remove the if then statement and do a msgbox to display the dt1,2,3 into values then it does for each row it has in the dataset

Comment: Is Start and End Date the range you want to display punch records for?  If so, given your control names, to me, the if `If dt3int > dt2int AndAlso dt3int < dt1int Then` seems to read  `if punchin > end date to display and punchin < begin date to display`  so it has to be after and before the display window at the same time?

Comment: If I need to supply more code or a picture of the GUI let me know. Or a code snippet from the SQL class I have imported

Comment: Try Hans Passant's suggestion -- I think you will find that you aren't setting dt before the loop, perhaps it got moved at some point?

Comment: So I get BC30512 Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Integer' to 'Short' on lines `Dim dt1int As Int16 = DatePart(DateInterval.DayOfYear, dt1)
        Dim dt2int As Int16 = DatePart(DateInterval.DayOfYear, dt2)` And Im getting object to string error on `Dim dt3 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(dr("PunchIn"))`

Comment: SO I have fixed all the INT16 lines by changing to type Integer the one im still trying is the Object to String `Dim dt3 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(dr("PunchIn"))`

Comment: All the Option strict issues are taken care of now. this bit of code still doesnt seem to be running `For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim dt3 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(CType(dr("PunchIn"), String))
            Dim dt3int As Integer = DatePart(DateInterval.DayOfYear, dt3)
            If dt3int > dt2int AndAlso dt3int < dt1int Then
                MsgBox("sadfdsafas")
            End If

        Next`

Comment: Did you move `dt = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0)` to **before** the loop? (I thought you might get a warning on that, but maybe not).  Are you wanting to display PunchIn records between Start and End Date -- if so see my earlier comment.

Comment: @phaedra It is currently before the loop. Also the goal is to show anything between the two dates.

Comment: Also since I am comparing the day of year It reads dt3 has to be larger than start andalso dt3 has to be smaller than enddate.

Comment: `the date is stored as a string in the database`  *facepalm*

Comment: I don't write applications for my job. Or for school I write them to help me get things done. I don't write applications for my job. Or for school I write them to help me get things done. I'm also storing it as an non standard standard form at in SQL that doesn't Parse correctly when pulled back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (I renamed dt1Int and dt2Int)

```
Private Sub getdata_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles getdata.Click

Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Dispose()
SQL.AddParam("@name", emplistadm.Text.ToString)

SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT EmployeeName, PunchIn, PunchOut, HoursWorked FROM PUNCHES WHERE EmployeeName = @name And CurrentStatus = 0 AND Processed = 0")

Dim dt1 As DateTime = startdate.DisplayDate
Dim dt2 As DateTime = enddate.DisplayDate

Dim dt1 As Integer = DatePart(DateInterval.DayOfYear, dt1) 'startdateInt 
Dim dt2 As Integer = DatePart(DateInterval.DayOfYear, dt2) 'enddateInt 

dt = SQL.SQLDS.Tables(0)

For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Dim dt3 As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(dr("PunchIn"))
    Dim dt3int As Integer = DatePart(DateInterval.DayOfYear, dt3)
    ' was:         If dt3int > dt2int AndAlso dt3int < dt1int Then
    ' should be 
    If dt3int > **dt1int** AndAlso dt3int < **dt2int** Then 
        dr.Delete()
    End If

Next

dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView
End Sub
```

Instead of
If dt3int > dt2int AndAlso dt3int < dt1int Then

use

If dt3int > **dt1int** AndAlso dt3int < **dt2int** Then

You're comparing to the wrong variables.

Comment: No dice I replaced dr.delete with a msgbox and it never popped up.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH I actually figured it out about 30 minutes ago I kept reading your comments and found a few of my issues basically i delete before first date and then in elseif instead of the same line do after the second date.so i run 2 delete commands the single command just would never work.